# Question with Common Lisp with replace the list

Tags: common-lisp

The question

[image]

the basic code is that

```
(defun my-replace (lst source target)
  "Replace every first-level occurrence of source with target in lst."
  (cond
    ((null lst) nil)                              ; stopping condition
    ((equalp (car lst) source)
     (cons target
           (my-replace (cdr lst) source target))) ; if head matches source,
                                                  ; replace head with target
    (t                                            ; otherwise use head and
                                                  ; check rest of the list
     (cons (car lst)
           (my-replace (cdr lst) source target)))))
```

but it cannot work

Comment: Often is it is helpful to report *what* is going wrong with the code when submitting a question. Is there a syntax error? Is the end result wrong? Does running the code cause demons to be summoned which destroy the world?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work fine

```
(defun my-replace (lst source target)
"Replace every first-level occurrence of source with target in lst."
  (cond ((null lst) nil) ; stopping condition
        ((equalp (car lst) source)
          (cons target (my-replace (cdr lst) source target))) ; if head matches source, replace head with target
        (t (cons (car lst) (my-replace (cdr lst) source target))))) ; otherwise use head and check rest of the list
```

For example,

```
(my-replace '(a b c) 'b 2) => (A 2 C)
```

Maybe you should post what the error is.